# Adding and removing repositories or bundles from Bndtools

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, bndtools

This is a two part question concerning Bndtools repositories:

1. Suppose you have a bundle in a bndtools repository that you don't need and want to remove. Is there a simple way to do this. There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about removing unwanted bundles from a repository (there is plenty on how to add bundles!).
2. Is it possible to add repositories to an existing project? I have noticed that when I create a project that uses an Amdatu configuration that the resulting bundle will not compile due to not having the osgi.annotation bundle. It turns out that this bundle is in a repository called "Bundle Hub" (a repository that is included if you choose the Bundle Hub configuration) which the Amdatu configuration does not include (a serious oversight on the part of the Amdatu people!). Is there some way that I can add the Bundle Hub repository after creating a project? Is there a way of creating any new "user defined" repositories? If there is no need for a repository, is there a way to remove it from a project?

Someone please advise.

Answer (score 2):

bnd(tools) has a repository plugin model. This means that there are different ways depending on the repository used.

- `LocalIndexedRepo`, `FileRepo` – You have to go to the directory and remove the files from there. Don't forget to refresh.
- `FixedIndexRepo` _ This one is driven from a remote XML file so you will have to create a new index.
- `JPM` – There is a delete menu on the entries in the repository. You can also update from there.

You can also `-runblacklist` entries of the repository for the resolver. See the enRoute setup in https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.examples/blob/master/cnf/ext/enroute-distro.bnd for an example.

We are working on streamlining the repos, which will likely mean they will all get a menu to delete and update.